# Restrict AWS SSM PutParameter to parameters in a specific hierarchy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I know I can create a permission on GetParameter/DeleteParameter etc to restrict a user to items below a specific hierarchy, e.g.:

```
/MyApp/dev/*
```

Can I similarly prevent the user from creating parameters outside this hierarchy, and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about below policy?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:PutParameter",
                "ssm:DeleteParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameterHistory",
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:DeleteParameters"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/myparam/test/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeParameters",
                "kms:ListAliases"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```